# Get Firebase dynamic link click analytics data from BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a Firebase dynamic link and will like to get the click analytics data from BigQuery. I am aware that it is possible to retrieve the click data via Firebase Analytics API but I will like to know if it is possible to get the click data from BigQuery instead?

I have already setup Firebase to send data to BigQuery, based on my exploration, I found that the data collected there are all based on app usage. Events like `dynamic_link_app_open` do seem relevant but they don't give the complete picture because events outside the app are not collected.